# Remove Line Spacing of Pictures (scrartcl)

Tags: tikz-pgf, koma-script, line-spacing

While it was possible to remove the spacing between paragraphs, I could not figure out how to remove the spacing between lines (line breaks / new lines).

As shown in the first section of the following example `\parskip` allows to have the `tikzpictures` without a gap inbetween, but both explicit newlines (`\\`) in the second section, as well as automatic line breaks as seen in the third section introduce a gap.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parskip}{-1pt} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\card}[1] {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \fill[#1] (0,0) rectangle (5 cm,2 cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\card{black}%
\card{red}%
\card{blue}%
\card{red}%

\card{blue}%
\card{black}%
\card{red}%

\vspace{.5cm}

\card{red}%
\card{blue}%
\card{black}\\%
\card{blue}%
\card{black}%

\vspace{.5cm}

\card{red}\hspace{0pt}%
\card{blue}\hspace{0pt}%
\card{black}\hspace{0pt}%
\card{blue}\hspace{0pt}%
\card{black}\hspace{0pt}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

Adjusting `\baselineskip` had no effect....

Comment: Use \lineskip=0pt.  Boxes larger than \baselineskip are separated by \lineskip instead.

Comment: Does using option `parskip` but setting `\parskip` to a value <= 0 make sense? Wouldn't it be better to remove option `parskip`?

Comment: @Schweinebacke Only with that negative parskip could I remove the gap between the paragraphs, that was the reason.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks, that one worked, I am wondering why I did not found anything about that earlier.... If you write an answer I can accept it or otherwise answer it myself now...

Comment: But you don't need option `parskip`. And the vertical space between paragraphs in this case is the same a in the paragraphs: `\lineskip`. Using option `parskip` but then setting `\parskip` to something <= 0 (or even something << `.5\baselineskip`) does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baselines are normally spaced `\baselineskip` apart, but when needed `\lineskip` is added between the bottom of one line and the top of the next.  (The actual test involves `\lineskiplim`.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parskip}{-1pt} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\card}[1] {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \fill[#1] (0,0) rectangle (5 cm,2 cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\card{black}%
\card{red}%
\card{blue}%
\card{red}%

\card{blue}%
\card{black}%
\card{red}%

\vspace{.5cm}

\bgroup% make change local to group
\lineskip=0pt
\card{red}%
\card{blue}%
\card{black}\\%
\card{blue}%
\card{black}%

\vspace{.5cm}

\card{red}\hspace{0pt}%
\card{blue}\hspace{0pt}%
\card{black}\hspace{0pt}%
\card{blue}\hspace{0pt}%
\card{black}\hspace{0pt}%
\par\egroup

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]