# Deleting vertical space between figures

Tags: vertical-spacing

Please consider this file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
    \draw (0,0)--(1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1)--cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
    \draw (0,0)--(1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1)--cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}\par
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
    \draw (0,0)--(1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1)--cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
    \draw (0,0)--(1,0)--(1,1)--(0,1)--cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Obviously, the output should consist of four squares of the same size, two above and two below (plus the page number). What I got can be seen here:

[image]

As you can see, there is no horizontal space between the two top squares, and there is also no space between the two bottom squares. However, there *is* a small vertical space between the first pair and the second one. Why? And how can I remove it without trial and error. I know that adding `\vspace{-1pt}` at the right spot (that is, right after `\par`) solves my problem, but, precisely, that amount of space *was* obtained through trial and error.

Comment: you can use `\lineskip=0pt` in the center environment.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you. That works indeed.

Comment: For more information, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383339/remove-line-spacing-of-pictures-scrartcl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer, that I learned from the comments.

In such a situation (for more details, see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383339/134805) or chapter 12 of *The TeXBook*), the length of the vertical space inserted between the lines is equal to `\lineskip`. So, the problem gets solved by putting `\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}` (or `\lineskip=0pt`) after `\begin{center}`.